# Dynamic insert into with multiple values

Tags: php

This is my `index.php` file and it has a simple form but with jscript I'll add some more inputs dynamically, then I need to insert these inputs to my database.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="uid">
    <input type="text" name="cid_1" placeholder="cid1">
    <input type="text" name="cid_2" placeholder="cid2">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I've created `insert.php` as below. I just needed to type for each inputs but actually inputs will be added dynamically as I said, so I just need to apply while or foreach function I guess but I'm not that sure how to do, hope someone there can help me about this.

One more thing I need, In this case everything is working but it inserts everytime even if some inputs are empty. I could not found anything about this too.

Thank you for your help from now.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['uid']);
$cid1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cid_1']);
$cid2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cid_2']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (uid, cid) VALUES ('$uid', '$cid1'), ('$uid', '$cid2')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql)
?>
```

Comment: *"it inserts everytime even if some inputs are empty"* - Use a conditional `!empty()` for your inputs, and/or don't allow for NULL values in db. Btw, use a prepared statement; it's safer.

Answer (score 2):

From your SQL query I understood that under uid, you are storing dynamic "cid" values from input. So you are adding dynamic input fields for "cid".

In order to capture dynamic fields on server, you have to name your input fields as given below which will be posted as an array on server.

```
<input type="text" name="cid[]" placeholder="cid1">
```

Next you will loop through that array and save each input data in your table.

Complete code:

HTML

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="uid">
<input type="text" name="cid[]" placeholder="cid1">
<input type="text" name="cid[]" placeholder="cid2">
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
```

PHP

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','usename','password','table');

$uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['uid']); 
if($uid !== ''){
    if(isset($_POST["cid"]) && is_array($_POST["cid"])){
        foreach ($_POST["cid"] as $key => $value) {
            $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);

            if($value !== ''){
                // insert into table
                $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test ( uid, cid ) VALUES( '$uid', '$value' )");
            }
            else{
                echo ($key+1)." no cid field is empty";
                break;
            }
         } 
    }
}
else
    echo "uid is empty";
```

Comment: I think you don't need the is_array check, cause cid is already an array.

Comment: Also it breaks the loop whenever it finds a empty field, but there could more non empty field after that empty one.

Comment: Efe ALBAYRAK said "it inserts everytime even if some inputs are empty".  I was just blocking inserting cid values if one is missing with a message. One could save only non empty fields and shows message for empty fields.So there are many options and  Efe ALBAYRAK  did no say explicitly what he was up to if there is empty fields.

Comment: Well your `if($value !== '')` filters the empty fields. What I said is about the `break;` statement. It breaks the loop whenever it finds a empty field even if there is non empty field after this one. So you should not break. You just need to continue to the next field.